# String comparison in SQL query on Heroku Postgres

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, heroku, comparison

I saw the weird behaviour of Heroku Postgres yesterday. When I executed this sql query for string comparison:

`SELECT ('2013/12-25' <= '2013/12/')`

Postgres on my development machine (9.2.3, Mac OS X Mavericks) returned **true** (which is correct) while Postgres on Heroku (9.2.4) returned **false**!!!

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that these two instances of Postgresql [have different default COLLATIONS (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/collation.html) in the server configuration:

Try to check if this command outputs the same result on both servers:

```
show lc_collate
```

For your example different collations can show you different results. For instance:

```
SELECT (('2013/12-25' COLLATE "en_US") <= ('2013/12/' COLLATE "en_US"))
UNION ALL
SELECT (('2013/12-25' COLLATE "ko_KR") <= ('2013/12/' COLLATE "ko_KR"))
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/2117)</kbd>

Comment: It seems that both have the collation "en_US.UTF-8". When I tried to run the following query: **SELECT (('2013/12-25' COLLATE "en_US.UTF-8") <= ('2013/12/' COLLATE "en_US.UTF-8"))**, my machine returned **true** but Heroku Postgres got errors. Any ideas?

Comment: @AnhNguyen What Error?

Comment: ERROR:  collation "en_US.UTF-8" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (('2013/12-25' COLLATE "en_US.UTF-8") <= ('2013/12/' ...
                              ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: collation "en_US.UTF-8" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
SQL state: 42704
Character: 23